# Multiple JasperPrints in one JasperViewer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report that is basically a form with multiple empty fields and a serial number generated by the program. Currently, the user can only get one of this by time, so I would like that the user could select the desired quantity of copies, and then, the `JasperViewer` showed all the copies in one window, instead of multiple windows as the number of copies.  Thanks in advance.

**Apologize for bad English.

Comment: And what is the question? You should post your code

Comment: About the question: " I would like that the user could select the desired quantity of copies, and then, the `JasperViewer` showed all the copies in one window, instead of multiple windows as the number of copies", how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could have a list of JasperPrint objects and use an exporter to export them to one report.  However, I'm not sure if you could then use the JasperViewer to view them.

Each JasperPrint object does have a collection of pages though.  So, you could take the first JasperPrint object and append the pages from the other reports, using the addPage() method.

Comment: Exporter works fine (I'm using PDF exporter), and since it seems JasperViewer cannot open the PDF report created, I would like to launch it by using the open(File) method of Desktop class, but it's not working. That's a different issue anyway. Initial question is solved. Thanks.